# Show that $T^{-1}:Y \to X$ exists and is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator from a normed space $X$ onto a normed space $Y$. If there is a positive $b$ such that $$||Tx||\ge b||x||,$$ for all $x \in X$, show that $T^{-1}:Y \to X$ exists and is bounded.

My attempt:

Suppose $Tx =0$ then clearly $||Tx~||=0 \iff || x||=0$ and so $T$ is injective, that is $T^{-1}$ exists. We need now show that $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

This is where I am stuck. I have the following trail of thought, but I am not sure if this is correct:

Since they say $T$ is a b.l.o. from $X$ **onto** $Y$, we can say that $T$ is surjective. Now, for every $y \in Y$ then there exists an $x=T^{-1}y \in X$ and so \begin{align}||T(T^{-1}y)|| &\ge b||T^{-1}y|| \\
\therefore ||y|| &\geq b||T^{-1}y|| \\
\therefore \frac{1}{b}||y|| &\ge ||T^{-1}y||,\end{align} for every $y \in Y$. That is, $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

Is this correct?

Comment: I guess you should also check that $T^{-1}$ is linear but the rest seems fine.

Comment: @M.G Thank you :). How can I check that $T^{-1}$ is also linear using the given information? :)

Comment: Suppose that $T^{-1}y = w$ and $T^{-1}z = x$, then $T^{-1}(y+z)$ is the unique element $v$ such that $Tv = y+z$, however $T(w+x) = Tw + Tx = y + z$, hence $v = w+x$, i.e. $T^{-1}(y+z) = w+x = T^{-1}y + T^{-1}z$.

Comment: The $x$'s on the LHS of your final two inequalities should be $y$'s.

Comment: @JonWarneke . Thank you for pointing that out :). That was a typo :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you should also check that $T^{-1}$ is linear but the rest seems fine. Here is the proof.

Let $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ and $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$. Using the linearity of $T$ you've got
$$ \lambda y_1 + \mu y_2 = \lambda TT^{-1}(y_1)+ \mu TT^{-1}(y_2) \\= T\Big(\lambda T^{-1}(y_1) + \mu T^{-1}(y_2)\Big).$$
Then apply $T^{-1}$ on both sides :
$$ T^{-1}\big(\lambda y_1 + \mu y_2\big) = \lambda T^{-1}(y_1) + \mu T^{-1}(y_2).$$